# how to display next array value on button click?

Tags: php

I have a session array containing lessonid, lesson name and description.

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$_SESSION['lesson_ids'];
?>


<table>
<tr><td>Lesson name </td> <td> description </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" name="next" value="next">
</table>
```

In that session array, I have 3 sets of data. I want to display one lesson in the current page.

When I click next the button, I need to display the next one.

How can this be done?

Comment: How is this related to mysql? Where is the HTML form to submit the button? What is the structure of the session array $_SESSION['lesson_ids']; ?

Comment: Slightly related: Wouldn't it make sense to make this part of the url instead? /lesson/1/chapter/2/page/3

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_SESSION['lesson_id'];
```

...

to increase this value, use

```
$_SESSION['lesson_id']++;
```